# using .each() to iterate elements with similar class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a group of div elements. I called them di1, di2, di3 but there can be more.

Actually, I show them with this piece of code:

```
$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").find("div.di1").show();
$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").find("div.di2").show();
$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").find("div.di3").show();
```

I would like to use the function each of jQuery. Can you help me?

Comment: Why can't you just give them a class of `di` or something, or just select all `<div>`s?

Comment: If you can get all the divs with just a selector, for instance, `$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").find("div")` or `$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").find(".some_common_class")`, you won't need the function `each` to show them all, just append it to the selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to perform more actions except just showing the elements, here is how to use the `.each()`:

```
$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo div").each(function(index) {
    var currentClassName = $(this).attr("class");
    if (currentClassName.length > 2 && currentClassName.substr(0, 2) == "di") {
        $(this).show();
        //you can do more actions here...
    }
});
```

[​Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp9jc/).

If you just want to show them, no need in `.each()` you can use the `.filter()` method:

```
$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo div").filter(function() {
    var currentClassName = $(this).attr("class");
    return (currentClassName.length > 2 && currentClassName.substr(0, 2) == "di");
}).show();
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp9jc/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use just `$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo div").show();`

Comment: With a common class for all `<div>`, this will be perfect.

Comment: Thank you all. Ican't Use $("#elenco_elimina_gruppo div").show(); because I have got this code:
    <li>
    <div class="d1">John Doe</div>
    <div class="d2">John Paul</div>

Comment: Hi Danil, I can't use that, because I have div called di1,di2,di3,di4,di5 etc I need to show di1,di3,di5 You method show all. Thanks

Comment: thank you all. I did the job with this code:
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#elenco_elimina_gruppo div").each( function(){
 var currentDivClass = $(this).attr("class");
        if (currentDivClass!="bottone_elimina"){
   if($(this).index() % 2 == 0){
     $(this).show();
   }
 }
 });
        });

Answer (score 1):

If it's just three divs, you can use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").find(".di1, .di2, .di3").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like -

```
$("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").children().each(function() {
    $(this).show();                    
});
```

See an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/nonocut/pNyuT/2/

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HELmC/) with the code I display below
The each function is quite simple, for example

```
$.each( ["di1","di2","di3"], function(item, index) {
     $("#elenco_elimina_gruppo div." + item ).show();
});
```

You can also use it like so

```
$.each( $("#elenco_elimina_gruppo").find("div.di1,div.di2,div.di3"), function(item, index) {
     $(item).show();
});
```

There are many ways to do what you are after, it's just a matter of taste. 
I prefer Speransky Danil's answer, and add a common class on all divs, but it is really your choice. 
For your convenience I added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HELmC/)